# Is this within the scope of a PhoneGap plugin?

Tags: ios, cordova

I've tried to figure out if the functionality I need is possible with a PhoneGap plugin and haven't found a clear answer.

I'd just like some clarification as far as if this is within the scope of a plugin.

The functionality would be...

1. Within the webview a user triggers a button.
2. A camera preview screen of custom size, not full
   screen, pops up over the webview.
3. The preview shows view from front facing camera except it's
   cropped to the custom size.
4. A video automatically starts recording for a set amount of time,
   then stops.
5. Once the video stops recording the preview screen goes away and the
   local path to the movie file is returned to a callback.

Is this all reasonable functionality for a phonegap plugin?

Comment: Already took more than that and I'm still unclear, so I'm asking for help.

Comment: In that case I apologize. Please disregard my previous comment. Also if you don't get an answer on this then I will set a bounty as soon as possible.

Comment: The topic of this question is interesting but the way it is asked makes it almost certain that you won't get any meaningful response.

Within the Cordova context, the functionality desired should be implemented as a plugin. So, are you looking for something more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely implement that functionality as a Phonegap plugin.

Possible steps that you can take are the following:

```
- Write the native code of the functionality first (Note: You can call and start activities through Phonegap plugin).
- Create a layout (Maybe, something that will overlay the webview with transparent background).
- Use the File API of Phonegap to access the movie file you just captured.
```